# Is there a function to veto those closing answers?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

I am quite new to Stack Overflow, but I wonder how many people are annoyed when they see a good question that is no longer active because it is closed.  Although I agree that some questions are vague or opinion oriented, I would like to see some thoughts from experts in the area that might be useful for people new to the subject.  I feel closing the question an overkill, given that we can down vote bad answers.

What's more, the power to close questions should be monitored and not abused.  I think a vetoing system allowing questions to be reopened if people think they are of value would be good.

What do you think?  Do we have such a mechanism in place already?

Comment: Yes, this feature already exists. Everyone who can close a question can also reopen it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions - a little more information there

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions

Comment: Downvoting a question, alone, without closing it doesn't prevent it from attracting low quality answers, it doesn't give the question author as much motivation to fix it, it isn't as strong as a signal to the question ban algorithm, it doesn't convey the same sense of authority, it doesn't allow them to be deleted if not fixed, etc.  Closing questions that are not in a state to be answered is *far* superior to *just* downvoting them.  Of course, the actions aren't mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 18):

People with enough reputation to vote to close do already have the ability to vote to reopen closed questions.

> Although I agree that some questions are vague or opinion oriented, I would like to see some thoughts from experts in the area that might be useful for people new to the subject. I feel closing the question an overkill, given that we can down vote bad answers.

This is not a good reason to leave questions open. We close questions because they are off-topic, too vague, or primarily opinion-based. Downvoting answers isn't the same as closing questions. Closing is a step towards *removing* these questions from the site if they aren't improved. We don't want people to answer questions here if they never should have been asked.

Comment: It continues to baffle me that people are like "omg this post might be _helpful_ to someone some day, therefore it should definitely exist, at all costs, on _this_ specific website". There's just no logic in it whatsoever but people seem to cling to it like it were gospel.

Answer (score 4):

> Although I agree that some questions are vague or opinion oriented, I would like to see some thoughts from experts in the area that might be useful for people new to the subject.

Stack Overflow decided to go for a Q/A format. That means one question, one answer. This  format has made Stack Overflow extremely popular.

However, this decision does come with some cons, one of which is that it doesn't allow to "*see some thoughts from experts in the area that might be useful for people new to the subject*". Those topics are often one question, thousands answers. That just doesn't fit this website.

But other people already filled this gap by creating communities which a forum format, in which discussions are more welcome than the Q/A things on Stack Overflow. A site like [quora.com](http://quaro.com) is an example of this.

> I think a vetoing system allowing questions to be reopened if people think they are of value would be good.

There is already a [reopen feature](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions):

> If you see a question and you disagree with the stated reason of its closure, you should first try to edit the question to improve it as much as possible. Read the close notice and any comments carefully to address concerns raised there. Closed questions that receive edits within the first 5 days of closure are automatically put into a review queue to be considered for reopening.
>
> Additionally, you can:
>
> 1. Leave a comment on the question itself calling for it to be reopened. Be detailed: explain why the question shouldn't have been closed. Be constructive: name-calling is as likely to drive folks away as it is win them to your cause. Remember, anyone on the site with at least 3,000 reputation points can vote to reopen a question - even if a moderator closed it.
> 2. Be sure that you've read the close notice and any comments on the question so you can address any concerns raised there. Addressing the concerns often means editing the post, which any user may do.
> 3. Flag the question for moderator attention. Again, explain why it should be reopened. There is more than one moderator, and moderators do reconsider their decisions.
> 4. If you have at least 3,000 reputation points, vote to reopen yourself.