# Asking questions on Stack Overflow is being banned

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I have been blocked from asking questions any further on Stack Overflow.

After referring to the Help Center, it says

> ban questions from accounts that have contributed many low-quality questions in the past

I feel very sad that people are been banned, or their posts have been closed, for asking questions. People ask questions not always to gain reputation, but because they don't know the answer.

A similar question might have been asked before, but that doesn't mean that everyone should understand the answer posted for the question, but the post is marked as a duplicate and gets closed. Stack Overflow should not force people to understand the question and answer to the post and allow them to ask a similar question. It is very sad that everyone might be not good at programming or English or asking questions and expressing themselves. But as experienced people Stack Overflow users should motivate them by explaining things to them and not demotivate them by blocking them.

I request that the Stack team please stop blocking and closing posts just because the Stack team may have good experience. People come to you with a hope, help them by not blocking and demotivating them.

Comment: I realize my close vote seems harsh, it is not about you personally. This question **is** a duplicate....

Comment: Users aren't banned *"for asking questions"*, they're banned for **asking bad ones, repeatedly**. If the specific case of duplicates, if you can't understand the answer than *mention that*, and be specific about your confusion, don't just ask the same question again and expect something different. SO isn't going to stop closing questions and blocking accounts; that's how the standard of quality is maintained.

Comment: You might find [this answer useful](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253354/578411)

Comment: @rene: not really a dup. This post is a feature request to disable banning...

Comment: stack gives reference to the similar question ask which is good, but even a similar post could have many questions in it and many different answers that doesn't mean it to be blocked. It cannot be always one sided judged by stack.

Comment: What do you mean *"judged by stack"*?! This is a **community network**, a question getting put on hold usually means that five other users agreed it should be. I didn't understand the first part of your comment.

Comment: @Mat really? Are you going to retag the post?

Comment: Sir I am just saying every one are not expert in everything. We learn from each other. If my one post goes wrong , or if I am a learner where I ask question that could be basic. So is it fair to block the user from asking any further questions.

Comment: Stack Overflow gets more than 7,000 questions *every day*. We simply can't accommodate every low quality question that comes in, it would destroy the site.

Comment: @nikalldway yes, it's fair, because it's a site for 'professional and enthusiast programmers', ie. those with sufficient skill and knowledge to ask non-bad questions and supply/understand non-bad answers.

Comment: Sir please refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-in-java is it basic question or something different which got so much votes

Comment: Also I like to thank some of people in Stackoverflow who have helped me to solve my problems. But it is just the very strict rules, I wish stack consider

Comment: @nikalldway, There is nothing wrong with basic questions such as that one, but _bad_ questions are not acceptable. Also note that such a question would probably not be accepted today, and that one is very old. If you have made no attempt to solve your problem first, then it is probably a bad question.

Comment: So is overrun with bad questions already.  SO contributors don't want the rules loosened off, which is why this question is getting downvotes.

Comment: so...... we become yahoo answers where people can keep on asking crap stuff without consequences? please let's not EVER do that

Comment: Please understand that there's a difference between a *simple question* and a *bad question*. There are plenty of *good* ways to ask simple questions. We want you to ask good, *useful* questions; nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: I [agree that duplicates should not count (as strongly)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/236947/) towards bans as other closures. Not much else I agree with here, though.

Comment: @JoshCaswell If a duplicate is a [different take](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) on some problem with different phrasing and synonyms for key words, then it probably shouldn't count toward ban at all. But if a duplicate can be found exactly by a title used, well, ...

Comment: Absolutely agreed, @EugenePodskal; that's why I think only negatively-scored duplicates should be factored into the ban.

Comment: @josh y dont you go and check my questions and tell me if they are duplicate. Dude there could be many people who first Google it later they come to stack where there question is marked as low quality question. So it means that the site is only for geeks. Certainly people would be scared to post questions. So it is like a student is afraid to ask a teacher question jus because he is afraid he might get blocked or post may get closed

Comment: You still have to clarify what you mean by "geek". SO is not a *forum*, it's a knowledge base. We do not want you to "ask teachers", we want you to write knowledge base articles. Does that distinction make it clearer?

Comment: What is your **exact** error message? Are you entirely blocked or just *slowed down* (e.g. asked to come back in a week before asking again)? There is a **huge** difference between the two states.

Answer (score 33):

> I request that the Stack team please stop blocking and closing posts

This is **never** going to happen. Stack Overflow is, per the tour, *"a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers"*, and one of the ways SO rose to its current prominent position is by removing posts (and, in some cases, users) that do not fit that model. There are plenty of other resources elsewhere on the internet, but if you want to participate on SO you need to do so within the existing guidelines.

Note that the majority of reasons for putting questions on hold *specifically mention how they could be improved*. It is not the end of the line for that question or its user, it just means that they might need to restate or clarify or add some additional information. The question can then be reopened, upvoted and answered and everyone involved is better off.

> I feel very sad that people are been banned, or their posts have been closed, for asking questions.

Then you misunderstand what is happening. We *like* questions on Stack Overflow, and people who can ask on-topic questions are very welcome. Users who get their accounts banned have *repeatedly demonstrated that they are **not** in this group*. The exact algorithm to trigger an account ban is not made public, but my understanding is that it requires multiple posts with multiple downvotes, not just the odd slip-up. And there is plenty of material in the Help Center to aid new users in writing good posts, *if they can be bothered to read it*.

> People come to you with a hope, help them by not blocking and demotivating them.

The problem is that **lots of people come to SO**, with varying levels of hope, competence and willingness to do their own homework. SO is not for every user to ask every question, and a lot of effort goes into keeping it that way.

---

In terms of your specific point about duplicate questions (required reading on why duplicates are a good thing: [Dr. Strangedupe: Or, How I Learned to Stop Worrying And Love Duplication](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/)), note that the usual case is something like the following:

1. New user wants to know *"How can I `foo` the `bar`?"*
2. If we're very lucky, they bother to search for it and find the answer *"Use the `baz` library"*.
3. They think *"but I can't use `baz` because [reasons]"*, so they ask *"How can I `foo` the `bar`?"* and are, for some reason, astonished when it gets closed as a duplicate.

Can you spot the mistake? Had they asked *"How can I `foo` the `bar` without `baz`?"*, and the first paragraph included *"I've read 'How can I `foo` the `bar`', but I can't use `baz` because [reasons]"*, then we're away. Try another one:

1. New user wants to know *"How can I `foo` the `bar`?"*
2. If we're very lucky, they bother to search for it and find the answer *"there's already a `Fooing` class for `bar`s"*.
3. They think *"but I don't know about the `Fooing` class"*, so they ask *"How can I `foo` the `bar`?"* and are, for some reason, astonished when it gets closed as a duplicate.

This time, they should have done some research into `Fooing` classes, reading related tutorials and reference documentation. If they can't figure it out, then they could either comment on the answer or ask a new question *about their specific issue*, starting with *"I was reading this answer about `foo`ing `bar`s, and I came across the `Fooing` class, but I can't figure out [specific query]"*.

Obviously, there are other, similar cases. *Be specific* about what you didn't understand, and *mention the source material* so others can understand your problem. If you just ask the same question again and it *doesn't* get put on-hold, you will probably get the same answers and **still not be able to understand them**.

Comment: [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)

Comment: Bruh I got banned because I asked a question about JavaScript called it "edge case", since you likely never need to use it in real life, and then some users kept downvoting it because it didn't fit the meaning of "edge case", and rather it was default behaviour that you should actually never use as best practice. 

i deleted it ofc, because it reduced Stackoverflow's "value", but after that i could no longer ask questions.

Comment: @Andi as I mention in the answer, I don't think a question ban is ever triggered by a single poorly-received question. Typically when people come to Meta and say "I asked one question and got banned" a mod subsequently posts a list of several deleted questions that contributed to the outcome - you can always flag one of your own posts and in the custom reason box ask for a list of your deleted, <=0 score posts to see what you could go about improving and undeleting.

Answer (score -15):

This is really ridiculous. Stackoverflow is rating a question based on the up votes. The question could be legitimate. But if people did not up vote then its not the mistake of the person who posted it.

Whatever algorithm the stackoverflow uses is really flawed.

Comment: SO doesn't rate the questions, the community does. And guess what: It does so by voting. If your question is downvoted, that's presumably because it *fails* being potentially useful and/or interesting. If it fails to attract any votes, then it's either in a very small niche, or mis-tagged into one and noone found it due to that. But if it doesn't attract any attention, it has negligible effect on the posters priviliges anyway...

Comment: Then please do not say that stackoverflow is a community site. Guys like you are making it commercial. You want more valid content for this website so it can scale well on SEO ratings. Stack over flow was there for so many years. They have always edited questionnaire and the vote system was meant for viewing the interesting articles. but now its used to guage a newbie questioning talent. Where else can a newbie ask help for ?

Comment: How does keeping the site useful make it commercial? And while good google-juice is good for SE, that's not the reason the community dedicates their time. Also, please explain how a bad question is useful. And why you do not want to ask any question anywhere else; Perhaps because they failed to moderate properly?

Comment: If a question is so bad or too bad, there are moderators. they can remove it. If the person keeps on getting banned like asking fake or unwanted question against policy they can ban him for few days. But banning some one for not getting enough upvotes. ?? don't you think its being silly ?

Comment: What stackoverflow is now doing is creating big hell of community tutorials for every programming languages. Thats all it will be after 5 years. everyone will have hundreds of thousands of votes for every question.

Comment: So, you are saying they should be allowed to throw as much crap on the side-walk as they possibly physically can, because sometime in the future there's a possibillity that something might stick, and there are a handful of (severely overworked) moderators who *alone*, without help by the community, should be able to collect *all* that trash by everyone? Nobody is getting banned for a handful of meh posts, it needs much worse.

Comment: Why do we have moderators ?!!!!! Please check those who are complaining. Please check their questions. Then speak.

Comment: I gained immense knowledge through stackoverflow. I do like quality contents. But banning a user mainly because they did not get up votes ? this is bad. Stack sends a message saying " your earlier questions were not received properly by the community. So you may be banned .. blah blah". This is bad.

Comment: you might be interested in taking a look at [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/): "...the only logical thing to do is to maximize the happiness and enjoyment of answerers. **If this means aggressively downvoting or closing unworthy and uninteresting questions, so be it.** Without a community of people willing to answer questions, it really doesn't matter if there are questions at all, does it?"